# What is the total size of your Linux installation and total partitions on the system?

Tags: linux, df

I am going through the [Linux documentation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/intro-linux.html#sect_03_06) and trying to answer the following questions

1. On which partition is your home directory?
2. How many partitions are on your system?
3. What is the total size of your Linux installation?

I used the following commands to answer 1 & 2 but how to answer 3?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           385M  1.7M  384M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       916G  9.0G  860G   2% /
tmpfs           1.9G  8.0K  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  6.1M  505M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           385M  128K  385M   1% /run/user/1000

$ df -h /home/rishik
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       916G  9.0G  860G   2% /

$ df -h | wc -l
9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two real disk partitions, `sda1` and `sda2`. Since `sda1` is 511MB and `sda2` is 916GB, your total size is roughly 917GB.

Comment: Off topic question and give a man a fish ...

Comment: instead of df use du
```du -sh```